# How to create an SVG "tooltip"-like box?

Tags: popup, svg, tooltip

Given an existing valid SVG document, what's the best way to create "informational popups", so that when you hover or click on certain elements (let's say ) you popup a box with an arbitrary amount (i.e. not just a single line tooltip) of extra information?

This should display correctly at least in Firefox and be invisible if the image was rasterized to a bitmap format.

Comment: Morais it might help if you narrowed the question a little.  Maybe a bit more specific about what technologies are available to you and which browsers you need to support (Firefox and what else?)  Just a suggestion.

Comment: The accepted answer is now out of date and but the one by Neil Fraser is still correct.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<svg>
  <text id="thingyouhoverover" x="50" y="35" font-size="14">Mouse over me!</text>
  <text id="thepopup" x="250" y="100" font-size="30" fill="black" visibility="hidden">Change me
    <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="thingyouhoverover.mouseover" end="thingyouhoverover.mouseout"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Further explanation can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121023190528/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgint/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Firefox 3.0.1 - is it supposed to?

Answer (score 52):

This question was asked in 2008.  SVG has improved rapidly in the intervening four years.  Now tooltips are fully supported in all platforms I'm aware of.  Use a `<title>` tag (not an attribute) and you will get a native tooltip.

Here are the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/title

Comment: Note: This does not seem to work when you add it dynamically using javascript.

Comment: Also, you can't style native tool tips :(

Comment: I used this with the d3 visualization framework to add a tooltip using javascript and it worked for me in recent versions of chrome and firefox. Code was something like `chart.selectAll("g.cell.child").append("title").text(function(d) { return d.size;} );`

Comment: This seems to work in Firefox (50.0) but not in Chrome (54.0.2840.100).

Answer (score 2):

Since the `<set>` element doesn't work with Firefox 3, I think you have to use ECMAScript.

If you add the following script element into your SVG:

```
  <script type="text/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[

    function init(evt) {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
        // Define SGV
        svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
        }
        tooltip = svgDocument.getElementById('tooltip');
    }

    function ShowTooltip(evt) {
        // Put tooltip in the right position, change the text and make it visible
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"x",evt.clientX+10);
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"y",evt.clientY+30);
        tooltip.firstChild.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null,"mouseovertext");
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","visible");
    }

    function HideTooltip(evt) {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null,"visibility","hidden");
    }
    ]]></script>
```

You need to add `onload="init(evt)"` into the SVG element to call the init() function.

Then, to the end of the SVG, add the tooltip text:

```
<text id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="hidden">Tooltip</text>
```

Finally, to each of the element that you want to have the mouseover function add:

```
onmousemove="ShowTooltip(evt)"
onmouseout="HideTooltip(evt)"
mouseovertext="Whatever text you want to show"
```

I've written a more detailed explanation with improved functionality at http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/tooltip

I haven't yet included multi-line tooltips, which would require multiple `<tspan>` elements and manual word wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:element")
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
   .append("svg:title")
   .text(function(d) {return d.Name+"\n"+d.Age+"\n"+d.Dept;}); // It shows the tool tip box with item [Name,Age,Dept] and upend to the svg dynamicaly
```