# How to add a tool tip for SVG which is converted from illustrator

Tags: svg

i have converted a map from vector to SVG in illustrator i am able give mouseover effect, link etc but i am not able give the tooltip effect even i tried many sample from stackoverflow, as the example are different what i see in my code also if impliement no effect i can find kindly help in this how to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#F79226;}
]]>
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M39.218,124.52c0.857,0,1.715,0.02,2.572-0.01c0.39-0.012,0.807-0.049,1.159-0.199
    c0.55-0.236,1.104-0.604,1.047-1.287c-0.046-0.563-0.667-0.563-1.076-0.713c-1.176-0.432-2.354-0.869-3.555-1.223
    c-2.095-0.615-3.657-2.063-5.355-3.305c-0.767-0.563-0.769-1.154-0.148-1.816c0.181-0.191,0.326-0.424,0.529-0.586
    c2.208-1.773,2.807-4.191,2.8-6.865c-0.002-0.857,0.051-1.715,0.067-2.572c0.011-0.598,0.05-1.238-0.389-1.695
    c-0.821-0.852-0.839-1.885-0.829-2.955c0.02-1.976-0.047-3.892-0.788-5.824c-0.569-1.485,0.075-3.097,0.843-4.519
    c0.061-0.111,0.218-0.177,0.263-0.291c0.853-2.139,2.386-3.614,4.247-4.951c1.068-0.768,1.708-2.154,2.483-3.301
    c0.653-0.966,1.542-1.634,2.536-2.159c2.089-1.104,5.048-0.211,5.847,1.952c0.502,1.359,0.333,2.912-0.74,4.073
    c-1.137,1.231-1.548,2.729-1.906,4.279c-0.203,0.878-0.058,1.592,0.869,1.93c0.98,0.359,1.355,1.137,1.654,2.061
    c0.671,2.078,1.477,4.071,3.408,5.392c0.702,0.479,0.53,1.911-0.312,2.833c-1.112,1.219-2.309,2.357-3.458,3.541
    c-0.413,0.424-0.811,0.867-1.182,1.328c-0.216,0.268-0.291,0.629-0.09,0.922c0.249,0.363,0.61,0.176,0.881,0.014
    c1.078-0.641,2.119-1.344,3.21-1.959c2.455-1.383,4.888-1.229,7.18,0.35c0.708,0.488,1.278,0.537,1.994,0.17
    c1.996-1.023,4.003-2.027,6.005-3.039c0.542-0.275,0.968-0.627,1.194-1.242c0.662-1.797,0.267-2.409-1.638-2.458
    c-0.837-0.023-1.75,0.209-2.368-0.633c-0.676-0.92-1.119-1.965-1.302-3.069c-0.126-0.763,1.584-2.128,2.539-2.12
    c0.39,0.003,0.777,0.146,1.17,0.183c0.436,0.041,1.011,0.269,1.181-0.347c0.171-0.613-0.04-1.214-0.671-1.481
    c-0.478-0.201-1.009-0.296-1.526-0.384c-0.91-0.154-1.823-0.317-2.742-0.382c-0.961-0.068-1.547-0.57-2.049-1.339
    c-1.112-1.7-0.615-2.838,1.455-3.063c1.045-0.113,2.114-0.005,3.163-0.1c0.932-0.085,1.376-0.909,1.02-1.692
    c-0.275-0.604-0.838-0.574-1.354-0.603c-2.568-0.142-5.137-0.371-7.706-0.36c-1.675,0.007-2.895-0.513-3.901-1.843
    c-1.113-1.472-2.37-2.834-3.533-4.27c-1.676-2.067-1.531-4.837,0.333-6.776c1.326-1.38,2.676-2.736,3.987-4.131
    c0.537-0.572,1.097-1.146,1.269-1.971c0.139-0.666,0.305-1.317-0.491-1.709c-0.116-0.057-0.232-0.141-0.311-0.24
    c-0.824-1.046-0.652-6.054,0.314-6.969c1.34-1.27,2.72-2.505,4.158-3.661c1.184-0.952,2.071-0.652,2.49,0.815
    c0.489,1.714,0.952,3.43,1.628,5.085c0.334,0.816,0.75,1.521,1.48,2.045c2.798,2.01,5.151,4.524,7.693,6.825
    c0.584,0.528,1.091,1.174,1.906,1.365c0.669,0.157,1.436,0.809,2.009,0.098c0.576-0.713,0.827-1.655,0.511-2.606
    c-0.123-0.37-0.359-0.703-0.555-1.047c-1.21-2.12-2.446-4.226-3.628-6.361c-1.037-1.872-0.726-2.778,1.354-3.382
    c1.661-0.481,3.344-0.612,4.8,0.803c1.066,1.036,1.145,0.96,2.297,0.015c0.408-0.335,0.822-0.666,1.201-1.032
    c0.729-0.706,0.674-0.994-0.356-1.31c-1.387-0.425-2.801-0.76-4.204-1.131c-0.778-0.207-1.451-0.544-2.019-1.164
    c-0.979-1.068-1.218-2.073-0.707-3.561c0.644-1.874,1.655-2.933,3.558-3.51c3.471-1.053,6.866-2.35,10.303-3.516
    c1.086-0.369,1.99-0.959,2.834-1.738c6.692-6.173,13.414-12.315,20.118-18.476c0.689-0.634,1.459-1.121,2.304-1.514
    c3.649-1.698,7.3-3.391,10.938-5.113c2.025-0.958,4.162-0.677,6.226-0.433c1.257,0.148,2.017,1.399,2.714,2.444
    c0.289,0.432,0.516,0.938,0.641,1.442c0.461,1.852,1.89,2.572,3.49,3.158c0.648,0.238,1.175,0.203,1.579-0.356
    c1.057-1.464,2.777-2.515,2.827-4.615c0.016-0.707,0.523-1.024,1.205-1.046c0.528-0.016,1.058,0.006,1.583-0.031
    c1.084-0.077,1.712,0.424,2.077,1.431c0.655,1.81,1.72,3.413,2.684,5.065c0.404,0.692,0.822,1.359,1.727,1.487
    c0.554,0.079,0.932,0.471,1.301,0.851c1.196,1.23,2.385,2.468,3.585,3.694c0.479,0.49,0.768,1.034,0.811,1.743
    c0.112,1.817-0.48,2.275-2.235,1.667c-1.958-0.679-2.147-0.611-2.598,0.932c-0.337,1.156,0.608,2.655,1.921,2.953
    c0.508,0.115,1.053,0.052,1.575,0.113c0.318,0.038,0.666,0.096,0.926,0.263c0.188,0.12,0.398,0.48,0.344,0.655
    c-0.405,1.311,1.471,1.913,0.878,3.395c-1.313,3.279-3.335,5.534-6.955,6.298c-3.372,0.712-6.721,1.364-10.186,1.143
    c-0.327-0.021-0.659,0.012-0.988,0.029c-0.822,0.045-1.16,0.516-1.138,1.303c0.02,0.711,0.38,1.104,1.093,1.135
    c0.659,0.028,1.318,0.027,1.979,0.039c2.101,0.037,4.058,1.404,4.471,3.439c0.541,2.658,1.177,5.274,2.1,7.824
    c0.132,0.364,0.17,0.777,0.178,1.168c0.052,2.524,0.13,3.059-2.573,2.917c-0.6-0.031-1.233,0.021-1.654,0.503
    c-1.092,1.248-2.576,1.781-4.044,2.386c-1.32,0.543-1.345,0.689-0.753,1.882c1.758,3.537,1.347,4.399-2.385,5.758
    c-2.168,0.788-4.131,0.925-6.21-0.336c-1.521-0.924-3.095-1.781-4.509-2.854c-1.397-1.061-2.86-1.455-4.599-1.346
    c-2.255,0.142-4.472,0.244-6.446,1.548c-1.741,1.15-2.416,2.914-2.77,4.805c-0.205,1.09,0.666,2.045,2.036,2.241
    c1.899,0.272,3.86,0.487,5.194-1.427c1.53-2.197,3.789-1.793,5.936-1.573c1.025,0.105,1.67,1.049,2.35,1.732
    c1.061,1.07,2.241,1.479,3.727,1.406c1.777-0.088,3.563-0.009,5.345-0.013c0.876-0.001,1.176,0.28,1.225,1.286
    c0.108,2.259,0.788,4.436,2.218,6.225c3.09,3.866,6.383,7.557,10.185,10.76c0.56,0.472,1.126,0.858,1.866,1.051
    c1.449,0.376,1.854,1.837,0.833,3.001c-0.562,0.643-1.271,1.148-1.886,1.748c-1.748,1.701-2.137,4.977-0.854,7.039
    c0.279,0.447,0.581,0.885,0.832,1.348c1.422,2.607,1.316,3.205-0.738,5.301c-2.883,2.941-2.543,1.848-1.715,5.988
    c0.337,1.684,0.812,3.33,1.37,4.955c0.638,1.855-0.089,3.924-1.707,5.01c-0.491,0.33-1.023,0.602-1.542,0.891
    c-2.429,1.357-2.877,3.682-1.104,5.844c1.632,1.99,3.31,3.943,4.917,5.951c1.623,2.029,1.654,3.154,0.258,5.354
    c-1.609,2.531-1.144,2.695-4.511,1.57c-3.567-1.191-7.165-2.289-10.746-3.439c-1.269-0.408-2.558-0.592-3.893-0.592
    c-3.167,0.002-6.336-0.023-9.503-0.09c-1.229-0.025-2.329,0.254-3.396,0.859c-2.121,1.207-4.285,2.34-6.413,3.535
    c-0.946,0.533-1.921,0.803-3.015,0.797c-4.619-0.025-9.238-0.025-13.858-0.002c-1.091,0.008-2.063-0.293-3.035-0.754
    c-3.28-1.553-6.595-3.033-9.86-4.615c-1.121-0.543-2.084-0.533-3.178,0.049c-4.627,2.461-3.589,1.055-4.89,6.131
    c-0.114,0.445-0.189,0.904-0.251,1.361c-0.256,1.877-1.373,3.047-3.21,3.385c-0.932,0.17-1.531-0.189-1.853-1.059
    c-0.528-1.424-1.075-2.838-1.576-4.271c-0.518-1.482-1.35-1.799-2.622-0.855c-0.951,0.707-1.819,1.525-2.722,2.297
    c-0.46,0.395-0.953,0.672-1.584,0.727c-1.455,0.129-1.831-0.094-2.317-1.512c-0.128-0.375-0.261-0.75-0.353-1.135
    c-0.259-1.086-0.938-1.662-2.034-1.877c-1.358-0.27-2.694-0.65-4.046-0.949c-0.81-0.18-1.33-0.596-1.321-1.463
    c0.01-1.039-0.607-1.697-1.299-2.336c-1.745-1.611-3.451-3.266-5.233-4.834c-1.017-0.895-1.279-1.949-1.498-3.262
    c-0.513-3.078,1.339-4.434,3.551-5.682c0.611-0.344,1.276-0.314,1.931-0.273c1.645,0.104,3.291,0.211,4.932,0.365
    c2.081,0.197,3.633-1.023,5.273-1.959c0.633-0.363,0.778-2.156,0.353-2.744c-0.354-0.488-0.814-0.34-1.239-0.135
    c-0.691,0.336-1.033,1.014-1.412,1.621c-0.549,0.879-1.294,1.25-2.316,1.203c-0.856-0.041-1.716-0.027-2.573,0
    c-1.104,0.035-2.011-0.102-2.669-1.236c-0.55-0.949-2.331-1.029-3.811-0.326c-1.25,0.594-2.493,1.227-3.662,1.965
    c-1.716,1.084-3.562,0.754-5.389,0.652c-0.772-0.043-1.11-0.684-1.278-1.342c-0.424-1.658-1.242-2.76-3.093-3.125
    c-1.35-0.264-1.508-1.408-0.461-2.336c0.951-0.844,1.982-1.52,3.378-1.346c0.714,0.09,1.449,0.016,2.175,0.016
    C39.218,124.559,39.218,124.539,39.218,124.52z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson i tried this these three but no output :( [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697232/how-do-i-show-a-bootstrap-tooltip-with-an-svg-object  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic  [link]  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102457/how-to-create-an-svg-tooltip-like-box

Comment: Using the `<title>` element per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643426/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-an-svg-graphic should work. Did you try viewing it in a browser?