# How to display a tooltip div when an SVG element is hovered

Tags: svg, tooltip

I requirement for an inline SVG chart which has a "more information" icon which should trigger "tooltip" on hover. See attached.[image]

I have the tooltip div styled and is used in other places but I also need it to trigger on the information icon inside the SVG.

I know I can't add the tooltip html inside SVG, so what other options are available to me?

The "chart" is just inline SVG taken directly from a graphic programme (Sketch in this instance). Am not using any frameworks or libraries like D3 or chartjs. Please don't suggest to use a library or framework as it's not an option.

Similar SO question but they don't answer my question:
[How to create an SVG "tooltip"-like box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102457/how-to-create-an-svg-tooltip-like-box)

Comment: the foreignObject tag will allow you to add the tooltip html in SVG. What is wrong with the linked answer? What code have you written so far? What problems need fixing with it?

Comment: Requirement to use custom tooltip and not the browser built-in tooltip

Comment: Show us what code you already have then. You say you have the tooltip div. Provide some minimal SVG markup too i.e. a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. I have a working solution now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty simple. It just requires a few lines of Javascript.

When we mouse over the icon, we position the popup and show it.  On mouseout, we hide it again.

Also note the `pointer-events="all"` on the icon, which ensures that the mouse is considered "over" an icon element even for the bits that have an invisible fill.

```js
var myicon = document.getElementById("myicon");
var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

myicon.addEventListener("mouseover", showPopup);
myicon.addEventListener("mouseout", hidePopup);

function showPopup(evt) {
  var iconPos = myicon.getBoundingClientRect();
  mypopup.style.left = (iconPos.right + 20) + "px";
  mypopup.style.top = (window.scrollY + iconPos.top - 60) + "px";
  mypopup.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePopup(evt) {
  mypopup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #33333f;
}

#mypopup {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#mypopup::before {
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 68px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g id="myicon" pointer-events="all">
    <circle cx="100" cy="150" r="14" fill="none" stroke="gold" stroke-width="2"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="144" r="2" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="98.5" y="148" width="3" height="10" fill="gold"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<div id="mypopup">
  <h3>Popup title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. getBoundingClientRect method was what I needed.