# svg hover rect shows popup of text paragraphs and icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Hi I found this worked [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384057/how-to-display-a-tooltip-div-when-an-svg-element-is-hovered?rq=1)

but it only works for one rect I have multiple rect's and paths that need to have text boxes on hover so that it is easier to read on a large infographic.

I understand it is from this that makes it only allow one id: var myicon = document.getElementById("myicon");
var mypopup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
I have tried to make them into classes but that wouldn't work.
Is there any documentation on this that I can work it out from or any suggestion? Thanks - all I need to know is how to get it to work for multiple not just one.

thanks

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried and does not work?

Comment: Classes should work, so sharing your code would help us identify the problem.

Comment: Hi I did my first jsfiddle but the style isn't showing maybe I put it in wrong. I added another popup link below it as it allows you to hover and read the text easier  The idea is to be able to read the text on hover not just as a title as there are some with lots of text in some boxes and to show in smaller screens to make it easier for the user to read and click to go to the linked page.

Comment: The fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/Theresa/822motx9/

Comment: The other problem is that when you hover past the rect the popover disappears.